# Samsung S3 asks for mobile data when I try to receive using ShareIt

Tags: samsung, mobile-data, shareit

A friend has Samsung S3 phone. Whenever he tries to activate receiving using Lenovo ShareIt, a pop up message raises asking to activate mobile data. Even after enabling mobile data, the WiFi spot is not created if mobile data is not connected.

- Is it a firmware problem, that the phone can't enable WiFi spot without mobile data active?
- Is there any fix or a workaround to make it works?

Answer (score 1):

This happends because the phone can't use Wi-Fi to connect to the internet and make a Hotspot in the same time, so it depends on the mobile data to connect to the internet. In order to use Wi-Fi to connect to an Access Point and create one, you would need an external wireless card or something like this.

Hope I helped, if I am wrong please correct me.

Comment: I'm not connecting to internet (neither wifi nor mobile nor usb) and shareit create it own hotspot. It works fine in most phones I have seen, only with this samsung s3, when shareit tries to create a hotspot, the phone blocks it and ask user to enable the mobile data connection. which seems weird, my 1st thought is a bug in firmware that don't let user create hotspot only if it connected to internet through mobile data.

Answer (score 1):

- Seems to be Samsung specific problem as you can see [Samsung S 3](https://community.verizonwireless.com/thread/832081)
  and [Samsung S4](http://forum.xda-developers.com/note-4-att/help/shareit-problem-t3373586/page2)
  There is no solution I could see on internet.
- Other users who had a problem in app review suggest using [Xender](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=cn.xende)

Comment: I will give xender a try and let you know.